# MediaCodec outputBuffer is always empty

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I have a problem with the `outputBuffer` inside my `onOutputBufferAvailable()` callback method. Everytime this callback method is called I check the `outputBuffer` using `outputBuffer.hasRemaining` method and this is always return `false`.

```
        codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);
                int rounds = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer,0);

                if(rounds > 0) {
                    long currentT = extractor.getSampleTime();
                    Log.i("CurrentT", String.valueOf(currentT/(1000*1000)));
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, rounds, 0, 0);
                     extractor.advance();


                } else {
                    // EOS
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                    Log.i("EOS","=-1");


                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull MediaCodec mediaCodec, @NonNull MediaCodec.CodecException e) {
                Log.i("error", "e");
            }
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId);

                Log.i("has", String.valueOf(outputBuffer.hasRemaining()));
                if (outputBuffer.hasRemaining()) {

                    b = outputBuffer.get();
                    Log.i("i", String.valueOf(b));
                    BAOS.write(b);
                    outputBuffer.clear();

                } else {

                    array= BAOS.toByteArray();
                    codec.stop();
                    codec.release();

                }
                 codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false);

            }


            @Override
            public void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec mc, MediaFormat format) {
                // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
                // Can ignore if using getOutputFormat(outputBufferId)
               // mOutputFormat = format; // option B
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason of the problem was wrong `MediaCodec` mode; was`MediaCodec.createByCodecName(...)`, should be `codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("audio/mpeg")`. After unsuccesfull tries getting byte using `get()` I finally ended up with `get(byte[] dst)` method. Working code below.

```
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId);

                    byte[] b = new byte[outputBuffer.remaining()];
                    outputBuffer.get(b);

                    for(i=0;i< b.length;i++) {
                        BAOS.write(b[i]);
                    }
                    outputBuffer.clear();

                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false);

                if (info.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) {
                    array=BAOS.toByteArray();
                    Log.i("array", String.valueOf(array.length));
                    FileTools fl = new FileTools();
                    fl.WriteFile(array);
                    codec.stop();
                    codec.release();
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is incorrect: info.flags == MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM
info.flags refers to multiple flags. You can't compare BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM to this. You must use:  info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM

Answer (score 1):

The position/limit markers on the ByteBuffers aren't updated by MediaCodec, you need to check the MediaCodec.BufferInfo object that you got to know the position and length of the actual payload data.

Comment: Do you mean `presentationTimeUs()` to get the actual position?

Comment: No, I meant reading the `offset` and `size` fields in MediaCodec.BufferInfo. However, the documentation of `getOutputBuffer()` does seem to document that it already is set up automatically: "The position and limit of the returned buffer are set to the valid output data"

Comment: Don't know why but my `info.offset` is always 0. `info.size` is 4608.

Comment: Yes, the offset is almost always zero. Anyway, since MediaCodec already sets it, this wasn't relevant if you use `getOutputBuffer()` at all. It's only needed if you use the older (pre-API 21) methods, where you call `getOutputBuffers()` ahead of time, to get an array of `ByteBuffer` objects. Then you need to apply offset/size to the existing `ByteBuffer` objects.